# Htaccess Redirect / RedirectMatch subfolder does not work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm quite new about modifying `.htaccess` and I'm having some problems getting some subfolders to be redirected to the homepage properly.

I wouldn't mind if it was just one domain but I recently bought some aged domains with installed wordpress.

Basically I have this URL: `http://hockeyplock.se/c/LTableCalculate.aspx?LId=162`
And I want to redirect it to: `http://www.hockeyplock.se`

So far this is what I have in the `.htaccess` but it does not do the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /c/(.*) /
```

Then I also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^c/(.+)$ http://hockeyplock.se/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But with no success.

I know the two methods are different things. I’m just trying to find out a solution to this asap.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your post to remove the offer of a monetary reward. The community feels that such incentives don't match the sprit of the site, and that allowing them would cause the quality of answers to decline (see [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25615) for details). If the answers you've recieved can't solve your problem, there's a question on Server Fault (a sister site of Stack Overflow) which may be of interest to you: [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/q/214512)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^c/(.+)$ http://hockeyplock.se/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi @Gerben
Thank you for your suggestion but the answer above from Ulrich solved the problem.

With your suggestion I was only able to get rid of c/LTableCalculate.aspx 

but then it'd be http://hockeyplock.se/?LId=164 which is not right.  I'm still getting the same

thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the followig in your .htaccess file in the root of your hockeyplock domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/c/.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.hockeyplock.se/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your suggestion. I've modify the htaccess and now I'm getting this
http://hockeyplock.se/?LId=106&TId=52      so basically it got rid of this bit /c/LTOverview.aspx        any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ulrich Palha

It worked!

May I asked what did you do? I tried different versions but I never was able to get rid of the "?" mark.

Thanks!

Comment: To remove the existing querystring you need to add a `?` to the replacement string

Comment: PS also read this post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/when-someone-answers-my-question-correctly-and-completely-what-should-i-do :-)